# tkinter, get file directory path as a variable for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I want the user to pick a file from file explorer and get its path into a variable, ex:

```
filepath = "C\User\Random_File\excel_archive.xlsx"
```

and use that variable to load it into a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.read_excel(filepath)
```

only thing I have now is this:

```
def fileopen():
 filepath = filedialog.askopenfile()
 label = Label(text=filepath).pack()
 df = pd.read_excel(label)

button_choose_file = Button(window, text='choose file', command = fileopen).pack()
```

but it doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work. Update `filedialog.askopenfile()` to `filedialog.askopenfilename()` and `pd.read_excel(label)` to `pd.read_excel(filepath)`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd

window = Tk()

def fileopen():
    filepath = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("xlsx", "*.xlsx"), ("all files", "*.*"))) #===assigns the path to filepath
    label = Label(window, text=filepath) #==Adds Label to window 
    label.pack()
    df = pd.read_excel(filepath) #==reads the excel file by fetching it from its path

button_choose_file = Button(window, text='choose file', command=fileopen)
button_choose_file.pack()

window.mainloop()
```