# Selecting files through directory explorer and saving path as variable

Tags: python, pyqt6

I'm creating a Python application that will allow the user to load data from a spreadsheet as a pandas dataframe, parse it, and merge it to an existing mysql DB.

I want the user to be able to navigate to the spreadsheet via a file/directory explorer and have it's file path saved as a variable that Pandas can then load as a dataframe. Similar to this issue but with PyQt6 and not tkinter: [tkinter, get file directory path as a variable for pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67538363/tkinter-get-file-directory-path-as-a-variable-for-pandas).

Unable to figure this out using QFileDialog.

Comment: Use `filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()`

Comment: Why is QFileDialog not the solution? It is clearly the equivalent of askopenfilename.